# jquery retrieve text next to radio (no label tag) -- have working on click but how to work on load?

Tags: jquery, text, radio-button, title

http://jsfiddle.net/acts7/wcL7c/9/
So I have this code.

(Before you suggest... no I cannot wrap a label around the text. I don't have access to it)

I am able to retrieve the text immediately following the radio input/button
when the user clicks on it, OR when they focus on it. In other words when the user takes action.

However; as I'm trying to make life better for those with screenreaders, I need to apply this text prior to clicking on it.

How can I loop thru the entire form, grab the text immediately following each input field, and assign that to the title attribute on the radio button?

QUESTION:: How can I get that text ... I already know how to assign it to the title attribute

THIS WORKS

```
$("input[type=radio]").focus(function(e) {
    var radioText = e.currentTarget.nextSibling.data
    //alert(radioText);
     $(this).attr('title', radioText);
});
```

THIS does NOT

```
$("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
    var radioText = $(this).currentTarget.nextSibling.data
    alert(radioText);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event handler, the `currentTarget` property of the event object is the element. In the loop `this` is the element, so just use that instead of `currentTarget`:

```
$("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
  $(this).attr('title', this.nextSibling.data);
});
```

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you!!!<insert space______________________ />
Why then was my .each function now working? I'm trying to actually understand / learn ... vs ... just finding an answer
$("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
    var radioText = $(this).nextSibling.data
    alert(radioText);
});

Comment: @user925737: The `nextSibling` property is a property of a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Comment: AHH! THANK YOU!!!! so its because I was doing [code] $(this) [/code] rather than [code] this [/code]